# How to align layout vertically like the 3-column layout (just vertically)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I want to have a vertically aligned layout(mobile). It consists of a main part (the main content) which should be in the middle. On the top and bottom of this part there should be like 200px of free space till the edge of the page (yeah like top: 200px). But in this parts there should be some text and it shouldn´t move.

This picture should explain it:

[image]

If something is not clear feel free to ask!

Code:

I tried it with "vh values"

```
#container {
margin-top: 10vh;
margin-bottom: 10vh;
width: 100vw;
height: 80vh;
}

<div id="container"></div>
```

so that's the basic thing, and if I do it like this:

```
#container {
width: 100vw;
height: 80vh;
}

#top {
width: 100vw;
height: 10vh;
}

#bottom {
width: 100vw;
height: 10vh;
}

<div id="top></div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

then it won´t fit in my screen, it's always a little bit too big so that I have to scroll...
Does someone of you have other ideas or improvents to solve this?

Comment: I think the words you are looking for are "header" and "footer". Show us what you have done to solve this problem yourself and explaing the problems you are having. This isn't a free code writing service

Comment: This has been "solved" many times over - is there a specific error or issue you are having? If so, you should show your work and issues. If not, I think I would recommend closing this question as too broad.

Comment: Looks more like a request instead of a problem?

Comment: I had many rudiments but none of them fitted like I wanted. I will edit my request I am sorry.

Comment: Try searching [jQuery UI](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages-single-page/) instead of asking how to design using css or javascript

Comment: @KirankumarDafda that is _terrible_ advice. This is a trivial task that does not require an entire library.

Comment: I do not understand line "there should be some text and it shouldn´t move". you want your main part to be vertically centre aligned?

Comment: @Turnip the question is totally depends on CSS and if asked here it means the user is not knowing much css then this is the better advice for user to complete the task.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda _" user is not knowing much css"_.  Exactly right. So educate them rather than telling them to use a library as a crutch.

Comment: @Turnip Agreed, my mistake !!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: fixed;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align:center;
  z-index: 10;
}
header {
  top: 0;
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;
}
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header>I'm a header</header>
<main>
  <p>I need your help ones again... So I want to have a (mobile) layout which is vertically aligned. It consists of a main part (with the main content) which should be in the middle. On the top and bottom of this part there should be like 200px of free space till the edge of the page (yeah like top: 200px). But in this parts there should be some text too & it shouldn´t move.
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
    I need your help ones again... So I want to have a (mobile) layout which is vertically aligned. It consists of a main part (with the main content) which should be in the middle. On the top and bottom of this part there should be like 200px of free space till the edge of the page (yeah like top: 200px). But in this parts there should be some text too & it shouldn´t move.
  </p>
</main>
<footer>I'm a footer</footer>
```